# Set DateTimePicker null in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

So I have a `DateTimePicker` and I want to set it to null when save it into a database, but by default it has the today's value. If I want to remove it and empty the `DateTimePicker` I am not able too.

I've tried to put it into the load form:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

It actually works, but if I want to set a date it will not display into the `DateTimePicker`. Do you have any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: You are not seeing anything because you break the format, not because you set it to empty.

Comment: I know it. But I can I set it to null and if I want to add a date I am able too. @PatrickHofman

Comment: What does a UI control have to do with the database? If you don't want to save the value enterd in the control, just don't pass it to the database. The default value for DateTime is DateTime.MinValue.

Answer (score 1):

I have once written a date time picker that accepts null values (and allows week numbers too, as a free bonus).

```
[DefaultEvent("ValueChanged")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[DefaultProperty("Value")]
[DefaultBindingProperty("Value")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DateTimePickerDesigner, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public class NullableDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    #region Externals
    private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    private const int MCM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int MCM_GETMINREQRECT = (MCM_FIRST + 9);
    private const int MCS_WEEKNUMBERS = 0x4;
    private const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = (DTM_FIRST + 8);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr h, int index);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr h, int index, int value);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int param, int data);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int param, ref Rectangle data);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
    #endregion

    #region General
    public NullableDateTimePicker()
    {
        this.ShowCheckBox = true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date/time value assigned to the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    /// The set value is less than System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.MinDate or more than System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.MaxDate.
    /// </exception>
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public new DateTime? Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!base.Checked)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return base.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                base.Checked = true;

                if (this.Format == DateTimePickerFormat.Short)
                {
                    base.Value = value.Value.Date;
                }
                else if (this.Format == DateTimePickerFormat.Time)
                {
                    base.Value = default(DateTime).Add(value.Value.TimeOfDay);
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Value = value.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets whether to show week numbers.
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ShowWeekNumbers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Week numbers
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.DropDown event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An System.EventArgs that contains the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr monthView = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
        int style = GetWindowLong(monthView, GWL_STYLE);

        if (this.ShowWeekNumbers)
        {
            style = style | MCS_WEEKNUMBERS;
        }
        else
        {
            style = style & ~MCS_WEEKNUMBERS;
        }

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        SetWindowLong(monthView, GWL_STYLE, style);
        SendMessage(monthView, MCM_GETMINREQRECT, 0, ref rect);
        MoveWindow(monthView, 0, 0, rect.Right + 3, rect.Bottom, true);

        //
        // Resize the surrounding window to let the new text fit
        //
        IntPtr parent = GetParent(monthView);

        Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle();
        SendMessage(parent, MCM_GETMINREQRECT, 0, ref mainRect);
        MoveWindow(parent, 0, 0, mainRect.Right + 6, mainRect.Bottom + 6, true);

        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

It shows a checkbox to allow null values, and the `new` Value property allows `null` too, so it works from both the designer and code.

Comment: It displays some erros because the `StringifyFormat` and `NativeMethods` does not exist

Comment: If I check the `CheckBox` it will set the DateTimePicker as Null?

Comment: No, the other way around.

Comment: If I unchecked it?